# Print all matching lines and the previous unindented line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

For example, lets say I want to find all lines with 'matching' and the previous unindented lines in this text.

```
Container 1
   some text
   some text
   matching text
   some text
Container 2
   some text
   some text
Container 3
   some text
   matching text
```

The result I want would look like this

```
Container 1
   matching text
Container 3
   matching text
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can there be more than one matching text in a Container part?

Comment: And can unintended lines contain _matching_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
    !/^[[:blank:]]/ {unindented = $0} 
    /matching/ && /^[[:blank:]]/ {print unindented; print}
' file
```

That remembers the last line that did not begin with whitespace. When you get to a matching line, use that value.

Comment: If an unindented line matches, this prints it repeatedly.

Comment: Very true. The regex should test for leading whitespace. Answer updated.

Comment: Ah, I was trying this and it did not work, but that approach should. 
awk '!/^[[:blank:]]/ {unindented = $0} /^[:blank:].*matching/ {print unindented; print}' test

Comment: Thanks. This was all very helpful, I was able to build on that and do even more of what I wanted with some if statements, and I just became a fan of awk.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^[^[:blank:]]/b do      # if line is not indented go to label do
//!{                             # if line is indented and if it
/matching/H                      # matches, append it to hold space
}
$b do                            # if on last line go to label do
b                                # branch to end of script
: do                             # label do
x                                # exchange hold buffer w. pattern space
/\n.*matching/p                  # if current pattern space matches, print
' infile
```

---

If you want to also print the non-indented lines that match e.g. `Container matching stuff` even if none of the lines in the indented block that follows matches, then simply change the last condition to `/matching/p` so as to remove the `\n.*` restriction and print the pattern space even if it holds just one (non indented) line that matches:

```
sed -n '/^[^[:blank:]]/b do
//!{
/matching/H
}
$b do
b
: do
x
/matching/p
' infile
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the detailed explanation. I failed to mention one criteria, that if the container matches, it is also printed. I am trying to insert and && operator to do this on the first portion before branching, but failing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `sed`:

```sh
sed -ne'/^[[:space:]]/H;$x;//!{$!x;//!s/\n.*match/&/p;}' <in >out
```

---

```
Container 1
   some text
   some text
   matching text
   some text
Container 3
   some text
   matching text
```

It considers a *Container* to be a contiguous span of not-blank lines which begin with a not-space character, and only prints *Containers* which match *match* one or more times from their second line on.

You could write that out to `grep`:

```
sed ... | grep -E '^([^ ]| .*match)'
```

...to get results like your example...